# Convert int to long without hurting performance speed

Tags: java, performance

I have the following code to count number of bits that is 1 in a long, where POPCNT.

```
public static int countBitsWithCasting(long i) {
        return POPCNT[(int)(i & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[(int)((i>>16) & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[(int)((i>>32) & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[(int)((i>>48) & 0xFFFF)];
    }
```

But because of the casting this code is on average 1.6 times slower then without casting

```
public static int countBits(int i) {
        return POPCNT[(i & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[((i>>16) & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[((i>>32) & 0xFFFF)] +
                    POPCNT[((i>>48) & 0xFFFF)];
    }
```

Is there a way to improve performance from casting long to int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most 64-bit architectures, casting `long` to `int` is free, since the lower half of 64-bit registers is directly addressable. E.g. on x86-64, if a long value is in `RAX` register, JIT compiler can just take `EAX` which makes the lower 32 bits of `RAX`.

Casting `int` to `long` is almost free, too. It's just a matter of one simple CPU instruction, `MOVSXD`. And yes, JIT compiler is smart enough to translate Java level cast
optimally.

---

Your second method `countBits(int i)` is faster not because of the cast. It differs *semantically* from the first method.

In Java, according to [JLS §15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), integer shift is masked with `0x1f`, while long shift is masked with `0x3f`. This means, in the second method `(i>>32)` is the same as `i`, and `i>>48` is the same as `i>>16`. So, the whole expression is equivalent to

```
return 2 * POPCNT[(i & 0xFFFF)] +
       2 * POPCNT[((i>>16) & 0xFFFF)];
```

JIT compiler can certainly do such a simple optimization, and as a result, you have 2 array reads in the second method instead of 4 reads in the first one.

---

If you want to count bits in a long, you can hardly do better than [`Long.bitCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#bitCount(long)).

`Long.bitCount` is an intrinsic method in HotSpot JVM. JIT compiler knows this method and treats it specially. In fact, `Long.bitCount` is translated to a single CPU instruction - `POPCNT`.